# UnsatisfiedLinkError: Getting this error in Telegram project

Tags: java, android-studio, unsatisfiedlinkerror, telegram

I downloaded the Telegram project from GitHub and imported to Android Studio. The gradle is build without any error but when I run it I get `UnsatisfiedLinkError` error.

From logCat:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: org.telegram.messenger.beta, PID: 11299
>                                                           java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void org.telegram.tgnet.ConnectionsManager.native_setJava(boolean) (tried Java_org_telegram_tgnet_ConnectionsManager_native_1setJava and Java_org_telegram_tgnet_ConnectionsManager_native_1setJava__Z)
>                                                          at org.telegram.tgnet.ConnectionsManager.native_setJava(Native Method)
>                                                          at org.telegram.messenger.ApplicationLoader.onCreate(ApplicationLoader.java:278)
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1035)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4638)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:155)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1378)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)

And the line error points to is:

> ConnectionsManager.native_setJava(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 14 || android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 15);

Got stuck here for 2 days. Help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anybody have a solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found the solution for it!
The project has C and CPP files that needs libraries which is in `.so` extension while running in devices.Recently they have deleted those files which is added in the commit section.That is why we get an exception while running.So we have run these C and CPP codes using NDK and Cygwin.

Download NDK:
http://developer.android.com/intl/es/ndk/downloads/index.html

Download Cygwin:
https://www.cygwin.com/

Removing prebuilt libraries. The source code for all libraries is (and always was) available here: https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/tree/master/TMessagesProj/jni

Comment: Can you explain how did you compiled native libraries to `.so`?i get errors like this:`jni/./libtgvoip/EchoCanceller.cpp:82: error: undefined reference to 'WebRtcAgc_Free'`